# Best practice to define multiple inputs with same set of fields

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.10

I am developing a framework that takes in an argument and uses input set based on it, but I'm not sure what is the best practice to codify it in Python.

For example, I have a set of inputs that I can select with the code:

```py
# Driver Code
input_arg = sys.argv[1]

if input_arg == "model01":
    inputs = model01_inputs()
elif input_arg == "model02":
    inputs = model02_inputs()
elif input_arg == "model03":
    inputs = model03_inputs()
else:
    return

driver_obj = SomeClass(inputs)
driver_obj.some_function()
```

I have been doing this by manually importing input files where these inputs are defined.

For example, some of my input files look like this:

```py
# model01.py
input1 = "x
input2 = "SomeStr"
input3 = list()

# model02.py
input1 = "y"
input2 = "AnotherStr"
input3 = list()
```

Another way of doing this I am contemplating is with the help of Enums:

```py
from enum import Enum

class InputTemplate(Enum):
    input1 = None
    input2 = ""
    input3 = list()

class Model01(InputTemplate):
    ...

class Model02(InputTemplate):
    ...
```

But with `Enums` too, I need to use a similar approach where I can't restrict the template of the input fields and need to instantiate them individually based on user input.

So I am not sure what should be the best approach to handle this so that:

- I can restrict what fields an input class can have,
- Some restrictions on some of the fields I can implement once and use everywhere,
- Pythonic implementation so that the code can handle multiple different input classes in the same driver code.

My current code is working, but I am not very pleased with the way I had to code the inputs. Any help is appreciated.